# what is problem that class and interface?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

first of all, EFProductRepository here is :

```
Namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete 
Public Class EFProductRepository 
Implements IProductRepository <<<<<<< error    
Private context As EFDbContext = New EFDbContext()

    Public ReadOnly Property Products As IQueryable(Of Product)
        Get
            Return context.Products
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
End Namespace
```

and then, IProductRepository is :

```
Imports System.Linq 
Imports SportsStore.Domain.SportsStore.Domain.Entities

Namespace SportsStore.Domain.Abstract 
    Public Interface IProductRepository 
        ReadOnly Property Products As IQueryable(Of Product) 
    End Interface End Namespace
```

my one problem is, Error BC30149 Class 'EFFroductRepository' should implement 'ReadOnly Properties Products As IQueryable (Of Product)' for 'IProductRepository' interface. SportsStore.Domain C:\Users\jeen0\source\repos\SportsStore\SportsStore.Domain\Concrete\EFProductRepository.vb

I don'k know what is problem....

plz let me know

No matter how much I google, I don't know

No matter how much I google, I don't know

Comment: Why have you tagged this with C# when it's clearly VB?

Comment: this VB question not c#

Comment: And unfortunately it's so poorly formatted (even in the source) that it's very hard to read. Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect example of why you don't lie to people and tag a question C# when it is specific to VB. This issue would only arise in VB so is irrelevant to C#. This:

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property Products As IQueryable(Of Product)
```

should be this:

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property Products As IQueryable(Of Product) Implements IProductRepository.Products
```

I'm pretty sure that VS would have been offering to do that for you if you had paid attention to what the IDE was telling you. I use ReSharper so it handles that stuff but I'm pretty sure vanilla VS does too.